# Signal drawing based on a constellation diagram

Tags: modulation, digital-communications, digital-modulation

Constellation diagram of a communication system is given.

[image]

[image]

S1(t) -> 0, S2(t) -> 1

Φ1 and Φ2 are basis functions and Tb is the bit period.

How can I draw S1(t),S2(t) and decision boundaries?

Comment: This is not a homework, I'm just studying for an exam and I couldn't find how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean "constellation" diagram.

Comment: What is \$r\$? Is that a typo, or a hint at the nature of \$\Phi_1\$?

Comment: @SimonRichter thank you, I fixed the typos and added some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I can guess how this is meant to be interpreted:

1. We have two basis functions, giving us a two-dimensional space in which to align symbols.
2. For successful decoding, the basis functions need to be at least linearly independent, and ideally, they should be orthogonal.
3. Testing for orthogonality, we multiply and integrate:

   \$\int\Phi_1(t)\Phi_2(t)dt = 0\$
4. Good thing that worked, otherwise we would have had to prove \$\nexists x | \Phi_1(t) = x\Phi_2(t)\$.

   For a two-basis system, that is somewhat sane, but with more basis functions, this starts to get really cumbersome. Fortunately, non-orthogonal systems are not that relevant in practice.
5. The amplitude is written in a manner that I find to be completely non-intuitive. Someone more enlightened than me could possibly comment on how that is useful beyond hinting at #7 below.
6. Constructing the time representation for each symbol is straightforward -- you multiply the symbol's constellation position with the basis function, and add these up (i.e. all you do here is a basis transformation of a vector):

   \$S_1(t) = (2V\sqrt{T_b})\Phi_1(t) + (-2V\sqrt{T_b})\Phi2(t)\$
7. This system is equivalent to a Fourier transformation with two points. \$\Phi_1(t)\$ is the DC part, \$\Phi_2(t)\$ is the base frequency. Decoding this schema works likewise, by multiplying the basis function again, and correcting the linear amplification resulting from the integration (probably that's why the \$1/\sqrt{T_b}\$ is there).

   The difference with the square waves is that you need to reconstruct the timing, which I assume is pretty much a given in that hypothetical scenario. If you don't have the timing information, the multiplication and integration become a full convolution, and you have to find the middle of the symbol.
8. The decision boundary would most likely be placed so that for each constellation point, the nearest valid symbol is selected. You have two valid symbols, so just draw a line in the middle between them.

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand your answer. So is it possible to draw S1 and S2 in (0,Tb) range?

Comment: @Jenny94, Simon's point 6 tells you how to do it. We can't go any further without knowing what \$\Phi_1(t)\$ and \$\Phi_2(t)\$ are.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Might the two diagrams with 1/√Tb be related to Φ1(t) and Φ2(t)?

Comment: Yes, that are the definitions I used (because using these make the most sense).

Comment: No, the definitions in the diagrams are sufficient.

Comment: So what exactly needed to draw S1 and S2 in (0,Tb) range?

Comment: Resolve it like in #6 (where I've inserted the \$(2V\sqrt{T_b}, -2V\sqrt{T_b})\$ coordinates for \$S_1\$ already, then likewise for \$S_2\$. Resolving these functions should give you a function where the end result is in volts, and the parameter is a time between \$0\$ and \$T_b\$ (in fact, you can use any value for \$t\$, but you will only get a nonzero result in that range).

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to solve the equation in #6.

Comment: Just insert the definition of the function. There is no sensible closed form, so a definition using ranges is easiest (especially as \$\Phi_1(t)\$ has one, and \$\Phi_2(t)\$ has two nonzero ranges only).

Comment: What are definitions of Φ1(t) and Φ2(t)? Honestly, I don't understand anything from the two diagrams below.

Comment: The definition for \$\Phi_1(t)\$ is \$1/\sqrt{T_b}\$ for \$0 \leq t < T_b\$, and \$0\$ for all other \$t\$. If you multiply that by the symbol value on the \$Phi_1(t)\$ axis, you get \$2V\sqrt{T_b}/\sqrt{T_b}\$ for \$0 \leq t < T_b\$, and \$0\$ for all other \$t\$. The right hand side of the addition works exactly the same, except that there are two nonzero ranges, \$0 \leq t < T_b/2\$ and \$T_b/2 \leq t < T_b\$.

Comment: Hint: the second diagram has a small error, and the line starting at \$-1/\sqrt{T_b}\$ is the correct one (\$\int\Phi_2(t)dt = 0\$).

Comment: So, the definition for Φ2(t) is -1/√Tb for 0≤t<Tb ?

Comment: Not quite. It changes at \$T_b/2\$ -- if it didn't, it wouldn't be linearly independent, and you couldn't build a two-dimensional symbol space around \$\Phi\$.

Comment: Φ2(t) is -1/√Tb for 0≤t<Tb/2 and 1/√Tb for Tb/2≤t<Tb, correct?

Comment: Exactly. You will notice that the integral over the entire function \$\Phi_2(t)\$ is zero, which is the only way the orthogonality condition #3 holds. Using this condition, you can finally test your solution for correctness: \$\int S_1(t)\Phi_1(t) dt = 2V\sqrt{T_b}\$, which is exactly the coordinate of the \$S_1\$ symbol along the \$\Phi_1\$ axis.

Comment: And could you give me a hint how to draw 2V √Tb / √Tb

Comment: You can simplify that (I've written the fraction with a \$/\$ to conserve space). Writing it as \$2V\frac{\sqrt{T_b}}{\sqrt{T_b}}\$ should make it obvious.

Comment: I've missed that :D

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem -- For a full understanding, I'd suggest you refresh [integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) and [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis), because that is essentially what is happening here (basis is changed between time signal and two-dimensional symbol space).